# Error cannot convert 'float*' to 'float' in return

Tags: c++, arrays, function

I'm new in C++ and I'm trying to learn about the arrays' behavior in functions. It's an attempt of matrix-vector multiplication.

```
#include <stdio.h>

#define N 4
float Gi[N][N] = {{ 0.0,         0.0,         0.0,         1.0},
                  { 0.0,  2.57142857,  3.42857143,  1.28571429},
                  {-0.0,  3.42857143,  8.57142857,  1.71428571},
                  { 1.0,  1.28571429,  1.71428571,  0.14285714}};

void mult(
        float vec_I[N],
        float vec_V[N]){
    int acc;
    for(int i = 0; i<N; i++){
        acc = 0;
        for(int j = 0; j<N; j++){
            acc += Gi[i][j]*vec_I[j];
            }
        vec_V[i] = acc;
    }
}

float solver(){
    float out[N];

    float I[N] = {0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 10.0};
    float V[N] = {0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0};

    mult(I, V);
    
    out[0] = V[0];
    out[1] = V[1];
    out[2] = V[2];
    out[3] = V[3];
    return out;
}

int main(){
    float outPrint[4];

    outPrint = solver();

    printf("| %d |\n", outPrint[0]);
    printf("| %d |\n", outPrint[1]);
    printf("| %d |\n", outPrint[2]);
    printf("| %d |\n", outPrint[3]);

    return 0;
}
```

When I try to compile, the compiler tells me "[Error] cannot convert 'float*' to 'float' in return", about the return of the solver function (line 34). I can't understand why.

Comment: What do you want `solver` to return?  A number, or an array of numbers? It looks like you meant for it to return an array

Comment: Replacing all the arrays with `std::array<float, 4>` would make this really easy to fix

Comment: I'd like to return an array of float numbers.

Comment: But also ask yourself, "Do I want to return a local variable that is about to go out of scope and become invalid?"

Comment: Matheus, if you are planning to have a function that returns a multi-array, you might want to learn about stack vs heap memory, pointers, keywords such as `new` (or `malloc` and `calloc` if you don't like `new`). If you try to return that array, declared and instantiated inside your function, when the function exists, that memory might end wipped. Also, the return type of your function is for a single `float` not for an array of floats.

Comment: There's a lot of mental overhead involved in correctly using `new` and `malloc` and, more often than not, a lot of debugging, so prefer to use [a library container](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/container) such as the `std::array` mentioned by Mooing Duck above. The experts don't touch `new`, `malloc`, or any other manually managed dynamic allocation until they have to and neither should you.

Comment: Or just pass the array into the function by reference and modify it that way.  Let the outside world worry about scope :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Arrays are not first-class citizens. As such they are not returnable by value. You will have to make use of a struct wrapper as such:

```
struct matrix_t
{
  float data[16];
};
```

Comment: The struct solution has worked perfectly. Thanks very much!